# MassTransit NullReferenceException in ThreadPoolConsumerPool

Tags: c#, asp.net, masstransit

When running MassTransit in ASP.NET. A `NullReferenceException` is being thrown, as per the issue reported here:
[Google Discussion Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/masstransit-discuss/Ms6thQfEhYg)

**Relevant Detail**
Does anybody know how to gracefully catch the exception when the AppDomain reloads?

The stack trace only goes as far as the MassTransit DLL:

```
NullReferenceException in ThreadPoolConsumerPool

Locating source for 'd:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs'. (No checksum.)
The file 'd:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs' does not exist.
Looking in script documents for 'd:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs'...
Looking in the projects for 'd:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs'.
The file was not found in a project.
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\crt\src\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\src\atl\'...
Looking in directory 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\VC\atlmfc\include\'...
The debug source files settings for the active solution indicate that the debugger will not ask the user to find the file: d:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs.
The debugger could not locate the source file 'd:\BuildAgent-03\work\8d1373c869590c5b\src\MassTransit\Threading\ThreadPoolConsumerPool.cs'.
```

Comment: You may want to add the relevant parts of the discussion here. Link-only answers are not a good fit for this site and I don't believe Link-only questions are much better.

Comment: nvoigt - I've added the relevant detail

Comment: This is only a suspicion but I think that Mass Transit interferes with the worker thread pool ASP.NET uses to handle requests. We had a similar issue with calling web services from within the ASP.NET application with asynchronous delegates - under high load the pool was ultimately depleted and the performance was terrible. Does it happen under high load or always?

Comment: Wiktor - this is during development under minimal load

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to catch any uncaught exception in global.asax:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/24395wz3(v=vs.100).aspx

Implement the error handler:

```
void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

and mark the exception as handled:

```
Server.ClearError();
```

Comment: If you publish the whole stack trace, maybe it will show that the exception happens before Application gets a chance to wireup the error handler. In that case you might be able to delay MT initialization till after the app had a chance to setup.

Comment: no, the application has definitely passed application_start and has been running for a substantial period each time this occurs.

Comment: a stack trace can be seen in the screen shot on the referenced link in my original question.

Comment: how about http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain.unhandledexception(v=vs.110).aspx?